# Pruning potato tree to shorten

Tags: tree-care, trimming

I have a potato tree that is round shape on the top about 10 feet tall. I’d like this to be about 3 feet tall but I will be cutting off all the branches. If I do cut it to a 3’ stump will the tree begin to grow new branches.

Marlona

Comment: I did not know about the Potato Tree or "Solanum erianthum is a species of nightshade that is native to southern North America and northern South America" Wikipedia.   Can you add a picture?

Answer (score 1):

[Solanum rantonettii](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/51043/i-solanum-rantonnetii-i/details)
is easy to prune as least as a young tree, but I recommend to do it in the spring or late autumn.
Usually, it produces a lot of new (and often unwanted) branches from the trunk.

[image: Solanum rantonettii summer 2022]
I think the name, potato tree, is used for several different species of Solanum. The photo of my Solanum rantonettii is provided for easy verification.